# Angular http client subscribe

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

In Angular 13, I am using using HttpClient `import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'` to get data from a Django API in my api.service.ts. The implementation of the get request is

```
 public getCalendar(): Observable<Schedule[]> {
    return this.http.get<Schedule[]>(`${this.API_URL}/schedule/`,
            {
              responseType: 'json',
              headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.accessToken}`)
            });
  }
```

I believe that the get request works fine, as the console.log inside the subscribe call prints out out my data array.

**However, in my html template I am not getting the schedule$ variables set. Can anyone help me with setting this up so that the schedule$ array is saved and accessible by the *ngFor.**

calendar.component.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let evnt of schedule$ | async">
  <li>Working {{evnt.title}}
</ul>
```

The interface definition for the data is

```
export interface Schedule {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    start: Date;
    end: Date;
    created_by: string;
    event_skaper: string;
    event_booker: string;
  }
```

In my calendar.component.ts

```
 schedule$!: Observable<Schedule[]>;

 public getCalendar(): any {
    this.apiService.getCalendar().subscribe(
    (data: any)  => {
      this.schedule$ = data;
      console.log(this.schedule$);
      // return this.schedule$;
    })
    console.log(this.schedule$);
    // return this.schedule$;
  }
```

Comment: I noticed you are not closing the <li> element. Maybe that is erroring on you...?

Answer (score 3):

You have already subscribed the `Observable` using `this.apiService.getCalendar().subscribe`.

So, it's no longer an observable. Change to

```
schedules: Schedule[] = [];
```

html

```
<ul *ngFor="let evnt of schedules">
  <li>Working {{evnt.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked. You also subtly omitted the "$" which was also necessary for my code. However, I am not sure if this is related, but is there a lag expected when running thin as part of ngOnInit()? The DOM renders but it takes ~30 seconds for the list to populate?

Comment: The list is now rendering, but intermittently. Is a lag or miss expected when running thin as part of ngOnInit()?

Comment: please check console network tab. 30 seconds is too much. `ngOnInit` is fine

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use async pipe in HTML you shouldn't subscribe the observable.

Because async pipe does that automatically see the [doc](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

```js
schedule$!: Observable<Schedule[]>;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.schedule$ = this.apiService.getCalendar().pipe(
                       // This is just for debug 
                       tap((data)=>console.log(data)));

 }
```

```html
<ul *ngFor="let evnt of schedule$ | async">
  <li>Working {{evnt.title}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually this assignation should be inside of  the ngOnInit to prevent having different observables  assignations and subscriptions

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clear

Comment: This improves the behavior of the html's *ngFor compared to Naveen's solution, but now console.log() doesn't show the array. In the console, the generic "Observable" meta data is returned. 

Is there a way to show the value of the array in console.log(). 

``` ngOnInit(): void { this.getCalendar(); console.log(this.schedule$) } ```

Comment: Yes, by using tap operator from RxJs 
 this.schedule$ = this.apiService.getCalendar().pipe(tap(data =>console.log(data)))

Comment: Tap did the trick.

Comment: Or for more simplify:  this.apiService.getCalendar().pipe(tap(console.log))